# I have 2 identical overhead projectors with bad diodes, but the diodes have different numbers. How do I find the right one that works?

Tags: wiring

I have 1 overhead projector that blows a new lamp right away. The correct lamp is rated 82Vac and 360W. I have 120Vac to the lamp, which makes sense why the lamp is blowing immediately. The only items in front of the lamp in the circuit are a fuse and a diode. Similar problem with my second projector except my voltage to the lamp is 24vac. I believe I have 2 bad diodes, but each diode has a different number even though they look very similar. I don't know which one could be the right one. The manufacturer can't tell me because they don't sell parts for these, they just warranty them out with full replacement. I don't qualify for direct replacement unfortunately. Does anyone know how to figure the right diode for what I need in this circuit? I'm an electrician but I don't work with electronic components. All I know is diodes allow current flow in one direction.....

Comment: Can you post close-up shots of the dead diodes?

Comment: I want to but I'm having difficulty figuring out how.....

Comment: If you are having trouble uploading the pics, just upload them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post the links here, we can take care of it from there

Comment: This question was already asked and has answers on EESE. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/284293/i-have-2-identical-overhead-projectors-with-bad-diodes-but-the-diodes-have-diff?noredirect=1#comment648585_284293

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was already asked/answered on EE.SE

Comment: Thank you to all for the help! That was also my question on the other site. I had posted it here not knowing that the other site even existed. My fault, still learning how this site really works. I appreciate all of the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link looks like the same question I agree.
 We really don't need a photo of the diode just the numbers will work. Diodes are rated on the ammount of current they can rectify and the peak inverse voltage (for general purpose types). The normal failure is the junction shorts until enough current is available to blow the junction open. The diode failure in this case is probably due to excessive current not the PIV, installing a diode with a higher current rating should do the trick. Make to note the stripe on 1 end of the diode and install the new one the same way so the polarity is correct for any wave shape or starting components that may be part of the circuit to get the lamp started.